# No route matches [PATCH]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, ruby-on-rails-4, routes

I'm attempting to submit a form but am running into the error

> No route matches [PATCH]

I've seen a variety of posts on this error but but in each one they only set `get` in their routes or some such error.  I've also had no problem submitting other forms with nearly identical routing and form structure.

So first, `Security has_many :stockholders`

My Form is as follows (location: `views/stockholders/edit.html.erb`):

```
<%=  simple_form_for @stockholder, url: url_for{action:'update', controller:"stockholders"}, html: {id:"stockholderform"}, update: { success: "response", failure: "error"} do |f| %>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="symegrid">
            <div class="form-inline">
                <%= f.grouped_collection_select :entity_id, [Org, Person], :all, :model_name, :to_global_id, lambda {|org_or_person_object| org_or_person_object.instance_of? Org? rescue org_or_person_object.fname + " " + org_or_person_object.lname rescue org_or_person_object.name}, label:"Stockholder", class: "names"%>
            </div>
            <div class="form-inline">
                <%= f.input :cert_number, label:"Certificate Number" %>
                <%= f.input :issue_date, Label: "Issue Date" %>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="submit_button">
        <%= f.submit %>
        </div>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

And my controller is:

```
class StockholdersController < ApplicationController
    def edit
        @stockholder=Stockholder.find(params[:id])
        @security=Security.find(params[:security_id])
        @company=@security.company
    end

    def update
        @stockholder=Stockholder.find(params[:id])
        @security=Security.find(params[:security_id])
        @company=@security.company
        if @stockholder.update(stockholder_params)
            redirect_to edit_security_path(@security)
        else
            redirect_to edit_security_stockholder_path
        end
    end

    private

        def stockholder_params
            params.require(:stockholder).perimit(:id, :entity_id, :cert_number, :issue_date, :shares_issued, :shares_repurchased, :shares_canceled, :shares_outstanding)
        end
end
```

Finally, my routes are:

```
resources :securities do
    resources :stockholders
end
```

Can anyone help me understand what's going on here?  I structured two models in exactly this way and didn't run into a problem.

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your route expects two more parameters, which are `:security_id` and `:id`.

```
simple_form_for @stockholder, url: { action: 'update', controller: "stockholders", security_id: @security.id, id: @stockholder.id }, ...
```

where `@security` may be `@stockholder.security` if not instantiated in the controller.

Or you can do it more elegantly:

```
simple_form_for [@security, @stockholder], ...  # url parameter is not needed
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Unfortunately I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: Got it, just had to remove the `url: { action: 'update', controller: "stockholders"}` part and add in the `@security` just like you said.